# Matching algebraic terms

Tags: regex

So I have the regex string

```
/((\+|-)?(\d+)(\w?)(\^?\d*))|((\+|-)?(\w)(\^?\d*)(\^?\d*)(?=\+|-))/g
```

It's supposed to match algebraic terms (a sign + a coefficient + a variable + an exponent), so a quadratic function in the `ax^2 +bx +c` form would be a set of three matches. It also matches signed and unsigned integers (e.g. `+5`, `-2`, `4`). However, it doesn't match algebraic terms on their own, like `x^2`, unless followed by an operator (+/-). This is fine in terms of the standard form, but if there was a polynomial function, like `x^3-x^2+x`, the last term wouldn't be matched.

I could just add more conditions to the regex to match more cases, but I feel like it's getting too cumbersome. So the question is, how do I do this? Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't really make it clear what I was actually trying to do with the regex. It's fixed now.

Comment: What language? This is not a trivial problem with a regex.

Comment: This isn't something to use RegEx for. Use some form of [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis) for [automata](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine)

Comment: Interesting idea. However, from what I read, you would have to use regex for tokenisation anyway, and lexical analysis isn't really in the scope of this little thought experiment of mine...

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following regex :

```
[+-]?(\w?\^?\d*)([+-]\w?\^?\d*)?([+-]?\w|\d)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mQ5yJ7/2)

The capture group `(\w?\^?\d*)` will match a variable with exponent and instead of or (`|`) for signs you can use a character class `[+-]`.

Comment: This fails to match one-off terms like `4x^3` and `2x`... Also, I was trying to keep each term (sign + coefficient + variable + exponent) separate, which led to some of the verbosity.

Comment: thanks :)
that works too, but it seems to lump a function into a single match string [see here](http://regexr.com/3asv1)

Comment: @HotelCalifornia Welcome but  if you want to match your expression within such texts it will not works!

Comment: yeah, the rest of the text was extraneous, I just meant that instead of matching `x^3-x^2+x` as `x^3`, `-x^2`, and `+x`, it matched the whole thing as one :S

Comment: @HotelCalifornia So just put whole of your regex within a capture group!